# Adapt Tortoise-TTS for another language

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, voice

I watched a YouTube video about voice cloning: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kfr_FZof_hs
It's an interesting topic, but this project's repository only supports English: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NxiY3zHN4Nd8J3YAqFsbYaOB71IiLE04?usp=sharing#scrollTo=JrK20I32grP6

I want to adapt it for Italian.

I am a beginner in machine learning.
What do I need to do to get TTC to "learn" Italian?
Is it necessary to train the model on audio files or rebuild the model, or what needs to be done?
Can you advise me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following where the creator answers this question.

Creator's answer:

Here is what you need to train this:

- a wav2vec or similar asr model for your language
- at least 10,000 hours of usable spoken language, with no environmental noises, music, etc. This does not need to be transcribed. I used audiobooks and podcasts for english.
- approximately 16 months total of v100 time

https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts/issues/5

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I found a model for italian huggingface.co/facebook/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53-italian/tree/main
But there is only one .bin file. There are no files: 'autoregressive.pth', 'classifier.pth', 'clvp2.pth', 'cvvp.pth', 'diffusion_decoder.pth', 'vocoder.pth', 'rlg_auto.pthh', 'rlg_diffuser.pth' Tortoise-TTS originally uses English model. It downloads these files (listed above) to the .models folder, and in the models folder (without the dot) there are scripts with the same names but with the .py extension. Is it possible to use Tortoise-TTS with a .bin model?